# Sonata Admin - Only allow show what logged in user has created

Tags: symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I've setup a sonata admin interface which allows users to create specific content, but how do I restrict users from editing content created by other users?

For arguments sake, a user logs in and creates a blog. 
In the list view of blogs, only the blogs *that* user created should be displayed.

Currently, everything is displayed to every user - I do have groups/roles setup to restrict access to admin areas, which works fine.

The only way I can currently think of only show a specific logged in users content, is to override the templates?

But, surely, this is an obvious and simple configuration setting?

Answer (score 14):

There are more options how to display only data of currently logged user:

The first prefered way is to use [Symfony's ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html), here are [more informations, how it works and how to do it in Sonata](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html).

If you don't want to use ACL, you can change the default queries by adding some condition to SQL query (DQL query), for example ' *WHERE adminId=5*'. This will be more work, but I will show you basic example, how to do it.

Change your definition of your admin services in services.xml by adding new setter *setSecurityContext*. I will use admin for listing and editing some products.

```xml
    <service id="acme_demo_admin.product" class="Acme\Bundle\DemoAdminBundle\Admin\ProductAdmin">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="product_group" label_catalogue="admin" label="Products"/>
        <argument />
        <argument>Acme\Bundle\DemoAdminBundle\Entity\Product</argument>
        <argument>AcmeDemoAdminBundle:ProductAdmin</argument>

        <call method="setSecurityContext">
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
        </call>
    </service>
```

SecurityContext is service, that contains informations about currently logged user.

In Acme/Bundle/DemoAdminBundle/Admin/ProductAdmin.php add setter setSecurityContext and change createQuery method:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoAdminBundle\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
// ...

class ProductAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * Security Context
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface
     */
    protected $securityContext;

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        //remove all routes except those, you are using in admin and you can secure by yourself
        $collection
                ->clearExcept(array(
                    'list',
                    'edit',
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->createQueryBuilder();

        //if is logged admin, show all data
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $queryBuilder->select('p')
                    ->from($this->getClass(), 'p')
             ;
        } else {
            //for other users, show only data, which belongs to them
            $adminId = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getAdminId();

            $queryBuilder->select('p')
                    ->from($this->getClass(), 'p')
                    ->where('p.adminId=:adminId')
                    ->setParameter('adminId', $adminId, Type::INTEGER)
            ;
        }

        $proxyQuery = new ProxyQuery($queryBuilder);
        return $proxyQuery;
    }

    //... configureListFields, configureDatagridFilters etc.
}
```

Users without role SONATA_ADMIN can't see all records.

Second step - secure some special routes, for exmaple **edit** - you should check if currently logged admin can edit the specified product.

You can create your [own security voter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/voters.html) (prefered solution) or use custom CRUD Controller.

In custom CRUD Controller: Acme/Bundle/DemoAdminBundle/Controller/ProductController.php overload **editAction**.

```php
<?php
    namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoAdminBundle\Controller;

    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;


    class ProductAdminController extends Controller 
    {
        public function editAction($id = null)
        {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $id = $request->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

            $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
            if (!$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {

               $adminId = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getId();

               $accessGranted = //here you should check if user with adminId can edit product with $id

                if (!$accessGranted) {
                    throw new AccessDeniedException(sprintf('Admin ID %s has no access to product with id %s', $adminId, $id));
                }
            }

            return parent::editAction($id);
        }

    }
```

As you can see, you can overload many methods and routes to add any functionality, you need. But as I said before, this is more work, so instead of overloading methods, first check if Symfony`s ACL (or just creating own security voter) is what you need in your project or not.

Comment: For securing the access maybe it would better with a [Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/voters.html).