# Sonata Admin: Let users only edit entities they own (ACL)

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin

I have Sonata Admin set up with ACLs. I have different users, groups and permissions which work fine. To achieve this, i followed [the Sonata Admin documentation on ACLs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html).

**So here is my question**: What is a clean way to ensure that backend (admin) users can only view, edit and delete the entities they created with Symfony's and Sonata Admin's built-in ACL mechanisms? Sonata Admin automatically stores the owner (creator) of the object once it is persisted in the ACL tables (from the [Sonata docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#roles-and-access-control-lists)):

> **Owner**:
>   when an object is created, the currently logged in user is set as owner for
>   that object and is granted all access for that object;

[The same question has already been answered on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843677/sonata-admin-only-allow-show-what-logged-in-user-has-created), but the answer does not explain in detail how to solve it with ACLs.

Comment: @pulzarraider, I saw you already answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843677/sonata-admin-only-allow-show-what-logged-in-user-has-created), but may I ask you to go into detail about how to implement that with ACLs in Sonata Admin? I don't know how to limit the list of objects in the list view of Sonata Admin to the ones the currently logged-in user owns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new Symfony bundle doing just that: https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsAclSonataAdminExtensionBundle

All you need to do is [enable ACL in Sonata Admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html), install the bundle and activate it. Pretty easy and effective, I use it in my Symfony2 project with Sonata Admin 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

I saw 2 ways to do that:

- Create a [custom AclVoter](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#create-a-custom-voter-or-a-custom-permission-map)
- Override your Admin Class' [`CreateQuery()`](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/276#issuecomment-3395968)

I was not able to do any of these for doing the very simple thing that I needed, but I think this is the idea.

Actually this is one of many Symfony things on which I spent many hours and thousands lines of code without big success... Such simple needs should not be as much pain in the arse...

Comment: The CreateQuery() is used only for the configureListFields
 public function createQuery($context = 'list')

Answer (score 2):

Don't grant the `EDIT` permission to the users. They can edit the instances they own but not others' instances.

I use this configuration:

```yaml
#app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    security:
        information:
            STAFF:    [VIEW, LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]
```

[Documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration)

Comment: Without the `EDIT` permission users that can `CREATE` records can edit AND delete only instances they own. I think the delete part is important :)