# SonataUser - Custom voter not called for LIST

Tags: security, symfony, acl, sonata-admin

In Sonata User Admin, I wanted to give users the ability to list/edit only users belonging to the same company.

So I have implemented a custom voter to manage this specific security rule on User Admin:

```php
public function supportsAttribute($attribute) 
{
   return in_array($attribute, array(
      'EDIT',
      'DELETE',
      'VIEW',
      'LIST',
   ));
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return in_array("FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface"
      , class_implements($class));
}

public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes) 
{
    if ( !($this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) ) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ( !$this->supportsAttribute($attribute) ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();
    if ( !($user instanceof UserInterface) ) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    // check if the user has the same company
    if ($user->getCompany() == $object->getCompany()) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }

    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```

Now, as a user, I can only modify users attached my company (as expected)
but I still see all users in the list.

[image: Sonata User Admin Grid]

*trutruc* & *machin* are from the same company so I can edit them. But I would like *chouchouette* & *truc* not to appear. Do I have to override the admin class' `createQuery()` method in addition to the voter ?

Finally the question is: **How to filter sonata users using ACL ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't**

At least I didn't find a way to use ACLs nor Voters to filter lists.
I had to override the admin's `createQuery()`

Comment: In addition to your question on https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1398 here is an example of how to inject the SecurityContext on the createQuery() method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843677/sonata-admin-only-allow-show-what-logged-in-user-has-created

Answer (score 1):

There is a bundle which enables filtering for lists as well: https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsAclSonataAdminExtensionBundle